# How to provide dynamic hover color in highmaps?

Tags: highmaps

see the below code:

```
states :{
    hover: {
        color: <dynamic color for each location>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter `point.pointAttr.hover.fill` after creating the chart to give specific points their own hover color. For example:

```
var points = $('#container').highcharts().series[0].data;

for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    if(points[i].options.code == 'RU' || points[i].options.code == 'US')
        points[i].pointAttr.hover.fill = 'pink';
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/bz2em9x5/) which has special colors for Russia and the United States.

Comment: This solution seems to have broken in Highcharts 5.0. Worked up to 4.2.7 (last 4.* version).